# Linux gpiod_get and GPIOD_ASIS

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

According to [GPIO Consumer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/consumer.txt) documentation, `flags` argument of `gpiod_get()` is optional.

> The flags parameter is used to optionally specify a direction and initial value for the GPIO.

But it also says [`GPIOD_ASIS`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/gpio/consumer.h#L38) flag instructs [`gpiod_get()`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L3222) function to not configure the pin.

> - GPIOD_ASIS or 0 to not initialize the GPIO at all. The direction must be set later with one of the dedicated functions.

Digging the sources down to [`gpiod_configure_flags()`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L3260), it seems that `GPIOD_ASIS` would actually be ignored since [`gpiod_get_index()`](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c#L3304) gets pin configuration from device tree...

Well, I am confused. For me it seems that documentation is contradictory. What is the real purpose of `GPIOD_ASIS`?
How to simply get a GPIO to be configured as described by device tree?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

Further explanation as requested by 0andriy.

`gpiod_configure_flags()` takes in two "*flags" parameters. `dflags` is basically what is sent from `gpiod_get()` while `lflags` are "looked up" from DT in `gpiod_get_index()` (and I am indeed using DT):

```
struct gpio_desc *__must_check gpiod_get_index(struct device *dev,
                           const char *con_id,
                           unsigned int idx,
                           enum gpiod_flags flags)
{
    // ...
    enum gpio_lookup_flags lookupflags = 0;

    // Line 3315:

    if (dev) {
        /* Using device tree? */
        if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_OF) && dev->of_node) {
            dev_dbg(dev, "using device tree for GPIO lookup\n");
            desc = of_find_gpio(dev, con_id, idx, &lookupflags);
        }
    // ...
```

This `lookupflags` variable in `gpiod_get_index()` becomes `lflags` in `gpiod_configure_flags()` below:

```
int gpiod_configure_flags(struct gpio_desc *desc, const char *con_id,
        unsigned long lflags, enum gpiod_flags dflags)
{
    int status;

    if (lflags & GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW)
        set_bit(FLAG_ACTIVE_LOW, &desc->flags);
    if (lflags & GPIO_OPEN_DRAIN)
        set_bit(FLAG_OPEN_DRAIN, &desc->flags);
    if (lflags & GPIO_OPEN_SOURCE)
        set_bit(FLAG_OPEN_SOURCE, &desc->flags);
    if (lflags & GPIO_SLEEP_MAY_LOOSE_VALUE)
        set_bit(FLAG_SLEEP_MAY_LOOSE_VALUE, &desc->flags);

    /* No particular flag request, return here... */ // <== Line 3274.
    if (!(dflags & GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_SET)) {
        pr_debug("no flags found for %s\n", con_id);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Process flags */        // <== Line 3280.
    if (dflags & GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_OUT)
        status = gpiod_direction_output(desc,
                !!(dflags & GPIOD_FLAGS_BIT_DIR_VAL));
    else
        status = gpiod_direction_input(desc);

    return status;
}
```

In line 3274, `dflags` is tested to have any direction flag and in 3280, direction is set.

Well, since `GPIOD_ASIS` equals to zero, it has no direction flags and `gpiod_configure_flags()` will return at line 3277 without configuring pin direction (as `lflags` states).

That's the point of my confusion. I could not find where pin is actually configured using DT info by following the sources if `GPIOD_ASIS` is used.

Comment: Is `GPIOD_ASIS` defined to 0?

Comment: Yes, it is `0` (although since it is an enum item we should not have to look into its value...). Thanks for asking @JonathonReinhart

Comment: @j4x can you please elaborate how did you come to the conclusion *it seems that GPIOD_ASIS would actually be ignored since gpiod_get_index() gets pin configuration from device tree...*?

Comment: Ok @0andriy. I just included the links to function implementation to not bloat the question (since the functions are quite small and straightforward), but I'll edit my question right now to let it clear. Thanks for asking!

Comment: So, if it’s still not obvious, “as is” literally means “don’t touch” the pin. The driver will do that at the point of explicit call to *gpio_set_direction()* as stated in documentation. If you want to configure it at request time you need to supply a direction. ACPI case slightly different.